# 12.04 `kernel panic not syncing IO-APIC + timer doesn't work`

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS onto my pendrive using the program recommended. After rebooting the system it showed this error:

```
[0.032000] kernel panic-not sycning: IO-APIC + timer doesn't work. try booting with
apic=debug and send a report. Then try booting with the 'noapic'option [0.032000]
```

Comment: I have permanent fix for this issue most youtube video where given temporary fix but this video gave me a permanent fix thank me later https://youtu.be/XzYuWEt6gQI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you first start Ubuntu you need to press the escape key and append "noapic nolapic acpi=off" to the boot options. Your computer is an older model apic isn't compatible with it. My dad's computer is the same way. If you ever get around to installing it on your harddrive you're going to have a doosy. You'll have to go into a liveCD, mount your harddrive as if you were actually using it and then edit your bootloader.

Comment: I get this with creating virtual machine using VirtualBox. How could add that to boo option in VirtualBox?

Comment: Just like he said-- hit escape when you see the boot options for ubuntu, then type the letter e... then copy and paste:   noapic nolapic acpi=off

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on my Lenovo E585.
I first added a `noapic` flag in the ubuntu kernel boot arguments.
The Ubuntu started without any problems, but I was not able to suspend(sleep) my laptop (due to APIC being disabled).
Then I followed [this link](https://jthegedus.medium.com/ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e485-15e1d601473f) and [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9tdut2/im_trying_to_install_ubuntu_1804_on_my_lenovo/) and it gives the solution to add this in the kernel boot arguments (in GRUB screen press e and append it to the line starting with linux)

```
ivrs_ioapic[32]=00:14.0 spec_store_bypass_disable=prctl
```

Later, I found that this was due to a BIOS problem, that was being fixed in an update by the manufacturer (Lenovo in my case).
So, I downloaded the BIOS update from https://support.lenovo.com/bg/en/downloads/ds503790 and after that, my Ubuntu works on my laptop without these kernel boot arguments.

Thanks

M. Saqib